# Prevent link from looking like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I need my links to look like links and not buttons. 
I've tried using removeClass to remove

```
class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover"
```

and removeAttr to remove

```
role="button"
```

but both don't work. How should I prevent these classes from appending or just plainly make my links look like links?

Comment: just don't call `$().button()` on your links

Comment: I'm not calling .button() on my links...

Comment: You probably call `.button()` with a selector that is incorrect (not specific enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API page of the jQuery UI button (http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-destroy):

```
$( ".selector" ).button( "destroy" );
```

> Removes the button functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

Comment: Yes this works, but why are they "buttonized" anyway? You probably call `.button()` with a selector that is incorrect (not specific enough)